# Is there any way to find the file which has error?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

There are multiple .gz files in my azure blob or file storage. Now, when I use the Data Factory pipelines to load the data, the copy data activity starts, & then I monitor my pipeline, the activity had failed due to some inconsistent data. Infact, the pipeline has loaded some records.

So, is there any way to find which specific file has an error in data?

Answer (score 0):

You can log the failed rows here.
[image: pic]

Comment: will that show me the filename or will that store the record?

Comment: you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance). The filename will not be stored. "The log files can only be the csv files. The original data being skipped will be logged with comma as column delimiter if needed. We add two more columns "ErrorCode" and "ErrorMessage" in additional to the original source data in log file, where you can see the root cause of the incompatibility. The ErrorCode and ErrorMessage will be quoted by double quotes."